# error while fetching rows in R

Tags: mysql, r

I want to fetch some data from my SQL server in R. The way I'm doing this is,

```
rs=dbSendQuery(con,"myquery")
data=fetch(rs,n=-1)
```

this works perfectly for a small table. However, for a bigger table, the fetch command says,

```
Warning message:
In fetch(ms, n = -1) : error while fetching rows
```

The problem still remains even if I restrict my rows (n=10). So, I'm not sure if it's a timeout problem or what.

What might be the case?

data shows,

```
1] creator ratio  
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of points I want to mention which can help `OP` in identifying and fixing problem.

**1)** Do not use `fetch`. Instead use `dbFetch`. The quote from R-help suggests as

> fetch() is provided for compatibility with older DBI clients - for all
>   new code you are strongly encouraged to use dbFetch()

**2)** Execute your query from `Query Editor` in `SQL Server Management Studio` and check for performance. Fine tune tables used query for indexes. Once ready and happy try it from `R`

**3)** If `query` is selecting many columns then it would be good to first try selecting just one or two columns.

**4)** I hope you freeing resources and closing connection in later part of your code. It can be done like:

```
# Free all resources
dbClearResult(rs) 
# Close connection
dbDisconnect(con)
```